# How to display a opensource UICollectionViewLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm new to objective-c. I'm trying to simply run and display a UICollectionViewLayout that I downloaded. It's called MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout (more specifically: http://code4app.net/ios/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout/529deb99cb7e84c30b8b5075). Either way,
it is essentially a .m and a .h file for an opensource calendar. I'm running xcode 2.4, so I just started an empty project because I don't have a Single View Application template option.

Here is the .h file, if it helps. Let me know if any extra info is needed to help out.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

extern NSString * const MSCollectionElementKindTimeRowHeader;
extern NSString * const MSCollectionElementKindDayColumnHeader;
extern NSString * const MSCollectionElementKindTimeRowHeaderBackground;
extern NSString * const MSCollectionElementKindDayColumnHeaderBackground;
extern NSString * const MSCollectionElementKindCurrentTimeIndicator;
extern NSString * const MSCollectionElementKindCurrentTimeHorizontalGridline;
extern NSString * const MSCollectionElementKindVerticalGridline;
extern NSString * const MSCollectionElementKindHorizontalGridline;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MSSectionLayoutType) {
    MSSectionLayoutTypeHorizontalTile,
    MSSectionLayoutTypeVerticalTile
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MSHeaderLayoutType) {
    MSHeaderLayoutTypeTimeRowAboveDayColumn,
    MSHeaderLayoutTypeDayColumnAboveTimeRow
};

@class MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout;
@protocol MSCollectionViewDelegateCalendarLayout;

@interface MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout : UICollectionViewLayout

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MSCollectionViewDelegateCalendarLayout> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat sectionWidth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat hourHeight;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat dayColumnHeaderHeight;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat timeRowHeaderWidth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize currentTimeIndicatorSize;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat horizontalGridlineHeight;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat verticalGridlineWidth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat currentTimeHorizontalGridlineHeight;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets sectionMargin;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets contentMargin;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets cellMargin;
@property (nonatomic, assign) MSSectionLayoutType sectionLayoutType;
@property (nonatomic, assign) MSHeaderLayoutType headerLayoutType;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL displayHeaderBackgroundAtOrigin;

- (NSDate *)dateForTimeRowHeaderAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSDate *)dateForDayColumnHeaderAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (void)scrollCollectionViewToClosetSectionToCurrentTimeAnimated:(BOOL)animated;

// Since a "reloadData" on the UICollectionView doesn't call "prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:", this method must be called first to flush the internal caches
- (void)invalidateLayoutCache;

@end

@protocol MSCollectionViewDelegateCalendarLayout <UICollectionViewDelegate>

@required

- (NSDate *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout *)collectionViewLayout dayForSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (NSDate *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout *)collectionViewLayout startTimeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSDate *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout *)collectionViewLayout endTimeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSDate *)currentTimeComponentsForCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout *)collectionViewLayout;

@end
```

Comment: It is easier to use just the example from GitHub as there are some other files required to make this library work. For example, you need to create a cell and some supplementary views. They're already created in the example.